# Saving Multiple Objects of Class (point Clouds)

Tags: matlab, point-clouds

I need to save multiple point clouds generated in a loop. I tried to save them in an array which returns an error:

> Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class 'pointCloud' is not allowed.

```
while i<=N
.
.
[imageDepth, pointCld] = getPointCloud(cp, maxDistance);
 imgDepthAll(:,:,i) = imageDepth;
 pointCldAll(:,:,i) = pointCld;
.
.
 i = i+1;
end
```

How can I fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: `pointCld` is, presumably, [not an array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pointcloud-class.html).

Comment: pointCld is an Object with properties Location, Color, Count, XLimits, YLimits, Z Limits

Comment: Yes, thank you, I can read the documentation fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second output (`pointCld`) is a [`PointCloud2` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/pointcloud2-object.html) that apparently does not support being placed into an array. Because of this, you would want to place them into a cell array.

```
pointCldAll{k} = pointCld;
```

If you want the actual XYZ or RGB data from this object, you'll want to access it using the following methods and then you could store them in a normal array.

```
xyz = readXYZ(pointCld)
rgb = readRGB(pointCld)
```

Or fetch the `Location` property and store *that*.

```
loc = pointCld.Location
```

Comment: The reason for the error is because he's trying to address an object like an array. He needs to access the `Location` property.

Comment: @excaza Ah updated that to include more info on the second output.

Comment: @excaza Ah missed that error message in the post. Apparently they don't support arrays. Interesting.

Comment: @Suever Unable to store PointCloud Objects in cell array as it is giving 'Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object'. I think I should store location property

Comment: @Basit Make sure that you define `pointCldAll` to be a cell array outside of the loop using `pointCldAll = cell()`